# swift 2.0 батон off / on не перезапускает блок

Tags: swift

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController  {

```
     var myButton = UIButton()

     var startTimer_a: NSTimer!  // первичный запуск
     var startTimer_b: NSTimer!  // интервалы повторов

override func viewDidLoad()  {
super.viewDidLoad()

    func puskA() {
    startTimer_a = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "runMeA",userInfo:nil,repeats: false)
    //первичный вывод изображения из массива

    startTimer_b = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(10, target: self, selector: "runMeA",userInfo:nil,repeats: true)
    //интервалы повтора вывода изображений из массива
} // скобка func puskA

    puskA()

}  // скобка закрытия viewDidLoad

     func runMeA() {

    /******************** блок button off  ****************************/
    // размеры кадра и его положение постоянны 
    self.myButton.frame = CGRectMake(265, 597, 120, 40)  // блок button = off 
    self.myButton.setTitle("off ", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    self.myButton.addTarget(self, action:"runMeG", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.myButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = true  // вспышка при нажатии
    self.myButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: .Normal) //.Highlighted...red цвет надписи

    self.myButton.layer.cornerRadius = 8 // радиус углов кнопки        
    self.myButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyanColor() // заливка кнопки

    self.myButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    self.myButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 18)
    self.view.addSubview(self.myButton)
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(myButton)        
    self.myButton.userInteractionEnabled = true; // true - false

   }   //     скобка закрытия func runMeAdd

/********** блок button On  *******************/

func runMeG() {          // запуск от программного button = off 

    startTimer_a.invalidate()  // выключение таймеров запуска...
    startTimer_b.invalidate()       

    self.myButton.frame = CGRectMake(265, 597, 120, 40)  // блок button надпись = On     
    self.myButton.setTitle("On", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    self.myButton.addTarget(self, action: "puskA", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside) 

    // при нажатии button когда надпись = "On" через action: "puskA" необходимо снова запустить  блок таймеров, 
    //однако в батоне action "puskA" не выполняется с выдачей по AppDelegate.swift сообщения 
    // Thread 1: signal SIGABRT = ? 

    //self.myButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: .Normal) // эти коды можно оставить или 
    //self.myButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor   // можно закомментировать не имеет
                                                                                                    // значения...
    //self.myButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 18)
    //self.view.addSubview(self.myButton)
    //self.view.bringSubviewToFront(myButton)  // конец блока button = off adds

    // startTimer0014.fire() не срабатывает...

   }  // скобка закрытия runMeG

   } // скобка закрытия class ViewController: UIViewController
```

// работает нормально, кроме попыток перезапустить блок таймеров по нажатию на button когда текст = "On"
// пробовались параметры :
// func puskA(firstName: NSTimer = startTimer_a, secondName: NSTimer = startTimer_b)
// puskA(startTimer_a, secondName: startTimer_b) - запускная от button ON
// до запуска Xcode ОШ не выдает...
// при запуске с параметрами при нажатии батон при надписи = ON дает ОШ = Thread1 BAD INSTRACTION
// коды компилируются Xcode 7.2  ON

[введите сюда описание изображения][13]

---

import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController  {

```
     var myButton = UIButton()

override func viewDidLoad()  {
super.viewDidLoad()

}  // скобка закрытия viewDidLoad

     var startTimer_a: NSTimer!  // первичный запуск
     var startTimer_b: NSTimer!  // интервалы повторов

    func puskA() {
    startTimer_a = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "runMeA",userInfo:nil,repeats: false)
    //первичный вывод изображения из массива

    startTimer_b = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(10, target: self, selector: "runMeA",userInfo:nil,repeats: true)
    //интервалы повтора вывода изображений из массива
} // скобка func puskA

    puskA()    // Xcode требует Expection declaration

     func runMeA() {

    /******************** блок button off  ****************************/
    // размеры кадра и его положение постоянны 
    self.myButton.frame = CGRectMake(265, 597, 120, 40)  // блок button = off 
    self.myButton.setTitle("off ", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    self.myButton.addTarget(self, action:"runMeG", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.myButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = true  // вспышка при нажатии
    self.myButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: .Normal) //.Highlighted...red цвет надписи

    self.myButton.layer.cornerRadius = 8 // радиус углов кнопки        
    self.myButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyanColor() // заливка кнопки

    self.myButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    self.myButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 18)
    self.view.addSubview(self.myButton)
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(myButton)        
    self.myButton.userInteractionEnabled = true; // true - false

   }   //     скобка закрытия func runMeAdd

/********** блок button On  *******************/

func runMeG() {          // запуск от программного button = off 

    startTimer_a.invalidate()  // выключение таймеров запуска...
    startTimer_b.invalidate()       

    self.myButton.frame = CGRectMake(265, 597, 120, 40)  // блок button надпись = On     
    self.myButton.setTitle("On", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    self.myButton.addTarget(self, action: "puskA", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside) 
    self.myButton.removeTarget(nil, action: nil, forControlEvents: .AllEvents)

    // при нажатии button когда надпись = "On" через action: "puskA" необходимо снова запустить  блок таймеров, 
    //однако в батоне action "puskA" не выполняется с выдачей по AppDelegate.swift сообщения 
    // Thread 1: signal SIGABRT = ? 

    //self.myButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: .Normal) // эти коды можно оставить или 
    //self.myButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor   // можно закомментировать не имеет
                                                                                                    // значения...
    //self.myButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 18)
    //self.view.addSubview(self.myButton)
    //self.view.bringSubviewToFront(myButton)  // конец блока button = off adds

    // startTimer0014.fire() не срабатывает...

   }  // скобка закрытия runMeG

   } // скобка закрытия class ViewController: UIViewController
```

Comment: Перед добавлением таргета нужно убирать старый

Comment: как это и для чего = ?

Comment: `button.removeTarget(nil, action: nil, forControlEvents: .AllEvents)` Для того, чтобы у кнопки экшены не накапливались, так получается несколько раз методы начнут дёргаться. Больше без стека ошибки подсказать не могу

Comment: как выцарапать стек ОШ = ?

Comment: button.removeTarget(nil, action: nil, forControlEvents: .AllEvents)  опробовал...не хочет...ОШ прежняя...

Comment: когда разместил button.removeTarget(nil, action: nil, forControlEvents: .AllEvents)  под  строкой self.myButton.addTarget(self, action: "puskA", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside) - ОШ пропала, но и перезапуск начального блока не выполняется...интересно однако...@markov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puskA() объявлен внутри viewDidLoad, и не существует вне его. Поэтому и ошибка. чтобы исправить вынесите его на уровень класса

Comment: ну и селектор в swift3 объявляется по другому `myButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("puskA"), for: .touchUpInside)`

Comment: до swift3 еще далеко...вынести puskA() или все вместе func puskA() = ? пробовал раньше все в теле класса, но требует Expected declaration ...пробовал подставлять параметры, но Xcode не соглашается...@Max Mikheyenko

Comment: всю функцию объявить в классе но не в другом методе

Comment: нарисовал как сделано сейчас ...после строки со звездочками...@Max Mikheyenko

Comment: вызов самой puskA должен быть во viewDidLoad

Comment: убрал  self.myButton.removeTarget(nil, action: nil, forControlEvents: .AllEvents) - поставил puskA() in viewDidLoad и после этого все стало как и было задумано...должник...@Max Mikheyenko